# .htaccess - Remove a word from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have a project directory structure as below

```
| project
 --| controllers
 --| views
   --| index.php
   --| .htaccess
 --| config
 --| .htaccess
```

Here's my main .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ views [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my view .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am able to redirect all my requests to **views/index.php**. When i go to ***www.example.com/project*** it will be redirected to ***www.example.com/project/views***.

**My main problem is i don't want to have views in my URL. If i go to www.example.com/project it should execute views/index.php but URL does not change. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this in main .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* views/$0 [L]
```

Then have it like this in `.views/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```